# How do I make custom .desktop files behave correctly in the Gnome 3 sidebar?

Tags: gnome3, .desktop, teamspeak

I've installed TeamSpeak 3 to `$HOME/Applications` and I've created a custom desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TeamSpeak 3
Comment=VOIP Client
Path=/home/tomas/Applications/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64
Exec=bash ts3client_runscript.sh
Icon=/home/tomas/Pictures/icons/teamspeak-3-icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

This shows up perfectly in Gnome 3 and I can pin the application to my sidebar:

[image: screenshot 1]

However, when I click the icon to launch TeamSpeak, the launched application spawns a new icon rather than being bound to the icon I pressed:

[image: screenshot 2]

Why does this happen? What mechanism does Gnome 3 use to decide which running applications are bound to which sidebar icons? Is there anything I can do to make this work?

My first guess was that it's because the actual application isn't launched directly, but through a bash script. I tried adding `exec` to the runscript to make the application be the direct child of the launcher, but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding this to my .desktop file:

```
StartupWMClass=<GnomeShellTooltipOfTheSecondIcon>
```

xprop can also be used to know the WM_CLASS.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/635839